# React hooks, reducer, context & initial state object. How do I make my API-call?

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, state-management

I followed a guide that showed how I could access and manage global state with just a few lines in a file called **state.js**:

```
import React, {createContext, useContext, useReducer} from 'react';
export const StateContext = createContext();
export const StateProvider = ({reducer, initialState, children}) =>(
  <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
    {children}
  </StateContext.Provider>
);
export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

**This is App.js**

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import { StateProvider } from './state';
import ToggleButton from './ToggleButton';
import axios from 'axios'

const App = () => {
  const initialState = {
    loading: true,
    navbarOpen: false,
    pages: [],
    album: []
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const requestOne = axios.get('http://example.com/pages');
    const requestTwo = axios.get('http://example.com/album');

    axios.all([requestOne, requestTwo]).then(axios.spread((...responses) => {
      const responseOne = responses[0];
      const responseTwo = responses[1];
      // What do i do here, how do i set this data?
    })).catch(err => console.log(err))
  }, []);

  const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'toggleNavbar':
        return {
          ...state,
          navbarOpen: action.toggle
        };

      default:
        return state;
    }
  };

  return (
    <StateProvider initialState={initialState} reducer={reducer}>
       <ToggleButton />
    </StateProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And this is my button that dispatches the toggle event: **ToggleButton.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { useStateValue } from './state';

const ToggleButton = () => {
  const [{ navbarOpen }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
  console.log(navbarOpen)
  return (

    <button
      onClick={() => dispatch({
        type: 'toggleNavbar',
        toggle: !navbarOpen
      })}
    >
      Toggle
    </button>
  );
}

export default ToggleButton;
```

The toggle is working and I really like this because I can manipulate state without having to pass down functions as props all the way where I want it.

**The problem is, since the "initialState" is an object that is passed down to the StateProvider, how do I save the axios response to the initial state, right now I feel confused because I have either setState() or any hook to call.**

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you must make use of useReducer within the functional component directly instead of calling it in provider value while rendering

```
const initialState = {
    loading: true,
    navbarOpen: false,
    pages: [],
    album: []
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'toggleNavbar':
        return {
          ...state,
          navbarOpen: action.toggle
        };
      case 'updatePagesAndAlbums': {
         ...state,
         ...actions.updatedState
      }
      default:
        return state;
    }
};



export const StateProvider = ({children}) =>{

    const state = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    return (
      <StateContext.Provider value={state}>
        {children}
      </StateContext.Provider>
    );

}
export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

---

Also StateProvider must wrap the App Component and the reducer must have a handler condition for updating state

```
const App = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useStateValue();
  useEffect(() => {
    const requestOne = axios.get('http://example.com/pages');
    const requestTwo = axios.get('http://example.com/album');
    const 
    axios.all([requestOne, requestTwo]).then(axios.spread((...responses) => {
      const responseOne = responses[0];
      const responseTwo = responses[1];
      dispatch({type: 'updatePagesAndAlbums', updatedState: { pages: responseOne, albums: responseTwo }});
    })).catch(err => console.log(err))
  }, []);

  return (
      <ToggleButton />
  );
}

export default () => <StateProvider><App /><StateProvider>;
```

Comment: Ok, is all of this done in the App.js file? or is it still 3 separate files? A bit confused ^^

Comment: @piedude, The code for StateProvider will be in state.js and the App component will be in App.js